# JS $.get Success rather then $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to tidy up some of my JS code and wanted to change my $.ajax
to $.get with a success function

```
function getresults(){

var reqid = getUrlVars()["id"];
console.log(reqid);
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/ser/id/",
        data: {
            'search_id' : reqid
        },
        success: resultsSuccess,
        dataType: 'json'    
        })
```

but rather then call another function can I just put it into this $.get?
I know its not correct but im getting a TypeError: callback is undefined at the moment and any help finishing/fixing the function would be great.

```
function getresults(){

    var res_id = getUrlVars()["id"];
        $.get("/api/ser/id/"+res_id+"/")
            .done(function(data){ 
                $.each(data); function ResultsSuccess(){

                    console.log('ResultsSuccess:='+this.pk+'Answer')
                    $('#result_header').text("Information on "+this.preferred_name.capitalizeFirstLetter()+", "+this.last_name.capitalizeFirstLetter());
                    $("#last_name").val(this.last_name.capitalizeFirstLetter());
                    $("#preferred_name").val(this.preferred_name.capitalizeFirstLetter());
                    $("#title").val(this.title);
                    $("#workphone").val(this.workphone);
                    $("#mobile_phone").val(this.mobile_phone);
                    $("#email").val(this.email);
                    $("#notes").val(this.notes);
                    $("#updated_by").val(this.updated_by);
                    $("#updated_at").val(this.updated_at);
                    $("#employstatus").val(this.employstatus);
                    $("#employer").val(this.employer);
                    $("#role").val(this.role_name);
                    $("#location").val(this.location_name);
                }
            })
}
```

Comment: what is `$.each(data); function ResultsSuccess(){ ` ???? Having something break in jquery

Comment: I think you mean: `$.each(data, function(responseData) {`, then replace `this` in the function with `responseData`

Comment: i think $.get vs $.ajax are same in your case because both have callback but $.ajax have more options then shortuct $.get

Comment: thanks @RoryMcCrossan works perfect< i knew I was a little off but was getting a little blind, If you want to pop it up as an answer I'll close it

Comment: @SpeedyH30 no problem, I added it as an answer for you.

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted on this one but oh well. Thought it was a fair question and it show the difference between using an $.ajax and $.get which is an issue I have been trying to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is a little off. You should use `$.each(data, function(responseData) {`, then replace `this` in the function with `responseData`:

```
$.each(data, function(responseData) {
    console.log('ResultsSuccess:=' + responseData.pk + 'Answer')
    $('#result_header').text("Information on " + responseData.preferred_name.capitalizeFirstLetter() + ", " + responseData.last_name.capitalizeFirstLetter());
    $("#last_name").val(responseData.last_name.capitalizeFirstLetter());
    $("#preferred_name").val(responseData.preferred_name.capitalizeFirstLetter());
    $("#title").val(responseData.title);
    $("#workphone").val(responseData.workphone);
    $("#mobile_phone").val(responseData.mobile_phone);
    $("#email").val(responseData.email);
    $("#notes").val(responseData.notes);
    $("#updated_by").val(responseData.updated_by);
    $("#updated_at").val(responseData.updated_at);
    $("#employstatus").val(responseData.employstatus);
    $("#employer").val(responseData.employer);
    $("#role").val(responseData.role_name);
    $("#location").val(responseData.location_name);
}
```